# Vertical connector between left (west) aligned boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have two connected nodes of different widths, which are aligned on the left (west) side, the connector between them is diagonal (or `-|` which I don't want for this application).

Here's what it looks like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, thick]
    \tikzstyle{all nodes}=[shape=rectangle]
    \tikzstyle{box}=[draw]
    % % Nodes
    \node[box, label=above:{Short box}](init)
    {This box is short};
    \node[box, below=of init.west, 
          align=left, anchor=west, label=below:Long box]
    (country)
    {
        this box is really really really long. Much longer.
    };

    % % Connectors
    \draw [->] (init) -- (country);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Boxes of different widths]

I'd really like that diagonal arrow to lead from the bottom centre of `Short box` to wherever is required on the top of `Long box` to make the arrow vertical.

Is that possible?

Comment: `\draw[->] (init)--(init|-country.north)`

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi. I think this probably *is* a duplicate of that other question, but I didn't find it by Googling, so maybe it's helpful that this question exists too.